# Phone number format javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I'm trying to format some phone numbers with regexp. The phone numbers i have stored are of diffrent length and all phone numbers have their country codes. Lets say a number looks like this: 00460708186681. I want that one to be formatted as: +46 (0)708-18 66 81. The first three groups are easy:

```
/00([\d]{2})([\d]{1})([\d]{3})/
```

Because the beginning of the number will always be the same. It's the last part where i dont know the length of the remaining chars (and i want them to be divided into groups of two).

Comment: Why are you doing this with a regex? It's not the right tool for this job, even if it can do it. It will be much faster, and probably simpler to just use fixed substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the following regex as your base:

```
00(\d{2})(\d)(\d{3})(\d{2})
```

Now add another pair `(\d{2})?` (note the '?') for every pair it's possible to have. So if the maximum number of pairs is 3, you do the following:

```
00(\d{2})(\d)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})?(\d{2})?
```

It's not pretty, but you need to do it that way in order to get them grouped correctly. Or you could simply do:

```
00(\d{2})(\d)(\d{3})((?:\d{2}){2,4}) // In this case it's 2 to 4 pairs of digits on the end.
```

To match the string, then you can manually add spaces in the last group which will contain all the digits after your initial formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the best solution here. Use this:

```
var num = new String("00460708186681"),
    i = 2,
    p,
    res = "+"+num.substr(i,2)+" ("+num.charAt(i+=2)+")"+num.substr(++i,3)+"-"+num.substr(i+=3,2);
while (p=num.substr(i+=2,2))
    res+= "\u00A0"+p;
return res;
```

Which will work for infinitely long numbers. A regex can't do that.

Comment: He's dealing with phone numbers. They might be of variable length, but there's certainly a well known maximum (and it's not large).

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution :

**Javascript:**

```
var num="00460708186681";
var res=num.replace(/([0+]{2})([1-9]{2})([\d]{1})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})([\d]{2})([\d]{2})/g,'+$2($3)-$4 $5 $6 $7');
alert(res);
```

Try above script on http://codebins.com/

Comment: `[0+]{2}` allows any number of 0s (1 or _more_ 0s, twice). The second part `[1-9]{2}` will not match `0010` for example which should be considered valid, you could use `[1-9][0-9]` instead. Also, there's no need to put single values inside `[]` (you've done it with `0+` and all the `\d`s) as that's an OR in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code done in TypeScript, but you can surely parse it into JavaScript:

```
const formatPhoneNumber = (phoneNumber: number, format?: string, code?: boolean): string => {
  let _format = format === undefined ? '---  ---  ---' : format
  let x = 1
  const newFormat = _format.replace(/-+/g, () => '$' + x++)
  let regex = '^'
  _format.match(/-+/g)?.forEach((c, k) => {
      regex += `(\\d{${c.length}})?`
  })
  return (code !== undefined && code === true ? '+' : '') + (phoneNumber.toString().concat(_format.split(' ').join(''))).slice(0, _format.split(' ').join('').length).toString().replace(new RegExp(regex, 'g'), newFormat)}
```

To test it, you can do:

```
const formatedPhoneNumber = formatPhoneNumber(600000000) // => 600  000 000
const formatedPhoneNumberWithCountryCode = formatPhoneNumber(237600000000, 'xxx xxx xxx xxx', true) // => +237 600 000 000
```

This example is perfectly modular, so you can do specify your own format (template) to have a different output!

*Note: I'm Cameroonian, that's why I used that strange template, Feel free to adapt the template to the needed phone number template*