# How to format Phone Number if 10 digits in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, format, dynamics-crm

I am trying to format a telephone number field in CRM 2011, but only if the field contains 10 digits.  Some of the numbers have extensions, but I want to ignore those for now.  I hacked existing code the best I could, but w/ my extremely limited knowledge of JS I will need some assistance. Any help is appreciated.  Below is what I have so far..

```
    var phone = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("telephone1");

    if(phone.length == 10)
    {
        phone.setValue( "(" + phone.substr(0, 3) + ") " + phone.substr(3, 3) + "-" + phone.substr(6, 4));
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting the phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973955/formatting-the-phone-number). You also have [Phone number format javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519699/phone-number-format-javascript).

Comment: What goes wrong with the [code you attempted](http://jsfiddle.net/96pj509r/1/)?

Comment: Hi showdev - there are no errors that come up, it just doesn't format at all.

Comment: Your code seems to format the number correctly in my [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96pj509r/1/). Maybe something different is going wrong with yours?

Comment: Put `console.log('Phone #: ', phone);` between the `var` and `if` lines and watch the console to see what you get. If you don't get anything, there's your problem.

Comment: CRM gets the value of "telephone1" in an alert statement, but only when there's no "if" statement ..  once I add that "if" back in, it fails when I replace the setvalue line to an alert of it's value.  I am doubting my code ...Is that definitely the right syntax on Line 3? ex: if(phone.length == 10)

Comment: the error is simple, you need to do a getValue() before checking the length. so the code will be: `var phone = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("telephone1").getValue();
    if(phone != null && phone.length == 10)
    {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("telephone1").setValue( "(" + phone.substr(0, 3) + ") " + phone.substr(3, 3) + "-" + phone.substr(6, 4));
    }`

Comment: That's exactly it Guido.  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

This might be an appropriate place for a little RegEx.

There are all sorts of edge cases in regards to phone numbers (invalid area codes and local exchanges, etc.), but this would work:

```
if(phone.match(/[0-9]{10}/))
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about trying to use an assignment statement like:

```
phone = ( "(" + phone.substr(0, 3) + ") " + phone.substr(3, 3) + "-" + phone.substr(6, 4));
```

instead of the phone.setValue();